# Do I need DATV to meet family at the Heathrow airport during my layover for a connecting flight?

Tags: uk, layovers, lhr

I am travelling from India and have 7.5 hours of layover at Heathrow airport for my connecting flight to Canada. I am arriving on terminal 4 and connecting flight departs from terminal 2. In the meantime of my layover a few of my friends wants to visit me at the airport so do I need DATV to meet them personally? Or is it possible to meet friends at the airport without any transit visa as I am not going out of the airport premises. Do I have to collect my bags and recheck-in if I have DATV? Is there any other possible way to spend the layover time with my friends at the airport?

Comment: ‘DATV’ means Direct Airside Transit - you have to remain airside. There’s no way you can meet your friends airside unless they happen to be flying out of LHR on the same day/same time / same terminal. However, assuming you have the correct visa for Canada you don’t need a transit visa at all.

Answer (score 8):

DATV means Direct *Airside* Transit Visa. The only thing it is good for is being allowed to *board a flight* towards an UK airport *when you do not expect to need to pass immigration there*.

If your friends are not traveling themselves, they can't come airside to meet you, so your only chance of meeting up is if *you* pass through immigration to meet them landside. Having a DATV is irrelevant for that.

You have two options:

- Pay to apply for a *Visitor in Transit* visa in advance, which will allow you to enter the UK.
- Hope the immigration officer will let you enter the UK under the *Transit Without Visa* scheme. Since you presumably have a visa for Canada you meet the formal conditions for this, and it is free. (However, beware that if I understand correctly they don't *have* to grant it, and the immigration officer may take the position that since you *can* stay airside for your transit, you *should*. The risk of this is probably small in practice).

There's no reason why you would need to see your baggage during the layover, if you can get the departing airport to tag it through to Canada (which they usually will if your flights are all on one ticket).

Comment: so If I want to see my friends during the layover I have to apply for Visitor in Transit visa even if I am not going out of airport premises? and If I have Visitor in transit do I have to go through immigration?

Comment: @KrushaBhatt You obviously have a Canadian visa or permanent residence card, so you don't need a visa

Comment: @KrushaBhatt: The thing that matters for visas an immigration is whether you need to _pass immigration_ or not. The "boundary" is the line between the airside part of the terminal building and the landside part of it. The outer walls of the terminal (or for that matter the airport's property lines) have no significance whatsoever.

Comment: I am travelling on Student Visa to Canada and my confusion is still the same. What should I do to meet my friends personally at the airport?

Comment: @KrushaBhatt: I don't really see how I can make it much clearer. Read the part of this answer after "you have two options".

Comment: @KrushaBhatt You should clear the UK border and present your passport open at the page with your Canadian student visa, the filled-out landing card (blue form) and connecting boarding pass to Canada (or e-ticket, if you don't have the boarding pass). Then meet your friends ij the arrivals hall. **No UK visa needed**

Comment: @HenningMakholm "the immigration officer may take the position that since you can stay airside for your transit (there are airside transfer buses between the terminals), you should" This isn't a thing - only if they suspect the traveller will abscond will they refuse

Comment: Alright. Thank you so much clarifying. Much appreciate.

Comment: @Crazydre: Indeed. Though who are we to know how suspicious the OP looks/acts in the immigration line? And according to the question title, they're meeting not just _friends_ but _family_, which might make them look more like a risk. -- All that being said, I agree the best plan is to bank on TWOV; the minuscule chance that you'd need to cancel the meetup is not worth the cost of an actual visa.

Comment: @KrushaBhatt For Heathrow flights, they will normally distribute the landing cards on the plane, so fill it out while onboard. If not, they're available in the immigration hall. Like I said, that, the Canadian visa and your connecting boardingpass or e-ticket